# C Using #define to point to or alias a function

Tags: c, embedded

I'm a little confused on if I can use #define to point to a function.  I have a codec/DSP who's tool automatically generates pages of code like this:

```
SIGMA_WRITE_REGISTER(address, data, length);
SIGMA_WRITE_REGISTER(address, data, length);
SIGMA_WRITE_REGISTER(address, data, length);
....
```

Then in another .h file they do this:

```
    #define SIGMA_WRITE_REGISTER( address, data, length ) {
/*TODO: implement macro or define as function*/}
```

Which helpfully doesn't define anything about writing registers.   That's fine though wrote some code for my micro to write registers over I2C and that seems to be working.  Now I don't want to just paste that code into the above define and have it instantiate it 1000 times.  I was hoping I could just use the is define as an alias to my function?

Something like:

```
#define SIGMA_WRITE_REGISTER(address, data, length) { my_i2_c_func(address, data, length)}
```

I tried something like this and it compiled, I'm not so sure it's working though.  Is this a valid thing to do or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can surely use `#define` to point to a full-fledged function or alias.

Consider a simpler example below, just for understanding

```
#define STRLEN(x) my_strlen(x)
```

and

```
int my_strlen(char *p)
{                      
     // check for NULL pointer argument?
     int x;

     for (x = 0; *p++; x++);

     return x;
}
```

now, in your code, you can use `STRLEN` as you wish.

Note: Regarding the presence of `{ }`, you can either get rid of them, or use a `do..while` loop, or define the function as a part of macro itself. Choice is yours. However, as MACRO is expanded during the pre-processing stage [resemble a textual replacement], you need to be extra bit careful about the `{}` and the `;` usage. The MACRO usage should not break the code.

Comment: It would greatly help if char *x = p; instead of int x = 0;

Comment: @user3629249: This would fix the loop, but the returned value would be wrong. I edited the code snippet to resemble an actual (yet naive) ``strlen`` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's (almost) valid, but you need a semicolon after the last close parenthesis and before the close brace.

The braces in the replacement are completely superfluous, so you'll remove them anyway, and then you don't need the semicolon you just added.  The braces give you a null statement after each statement block (and if you keep the semicolon in the macro, you also get a null statement after each macro invocation.

The comments in the `.h` file indicate that you can replace the macro with a function (call).  What you're doing is basically fine.

Comment: the semicolon at the end is not essential in the define line...he can add it after using the function in the main code which makes the code readable especially when coding with C !!

Comment: @user12448: Yup; once you remove the braces, the semicolon is not wanted in the `#define` — but until the braces are removed, it is needed.

Comment: I think the braces surrounding the function are totally useless. Apart of that you are absolutely right !!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SIGMA_WRITE_REGISTER my_i2_c_func
```